# How to update UseContext global state and reflect that change in every screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am dealing with react useContext and I and not able to update my golbal state value in each and every screen.

I am trying to change my theam color in App but it is reflect in that screen from where I change but when I navigate to another Screen I am not able to to see the change only default value is passing.

please help me with this.

I have tried to update my value and pass the value but I am not able to update it only shown in the same screen from where I have the feature of change theam color. but in another screen the change is not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps involved in implementing this.

1. Create the Context Provider: `createContext` lets you create the context provider.
2. Wrap the context provider around components that would access it's data: The context provider you created in the previous step must wrap all the components that would access data within this context. For your use case, of provided theme across your application you can place closer to the top level component of your application, you can place it either in App.js or index.js
3. Use the context: `useContext` is a React Hook that lets you read and subscribe to context from your component.

ThemeContext.js

```
import { createContext} from 'react';
export default const ThemeContext = createContext(null);
```

This essentially creates the context as mentioned in step 1. The value you pass to `createContext` will be the default value of the provider.

App.js

```
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import ThemeContext from '...path/to/ThemeContext.js';

export default function MyApp() {
const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme}>
      <SomeComponent />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As Mentioned in step 2. Place the provider in one of the top level components of your application. This means the provider should wrap all components that would read from it. For your use case, you can place it in App.js, or wrap it around a stack provider if you have one of those, or index.js. The state variables would live inside this top level components making their scope global to all the children the context provides to.

SomeComponent.js

```
import { useContext } from 'React';
import ThemeContext from '...path/to/ThemeContext.js';

export default const SomeComponent = () => {
const ThemeCtx = useContext(ThemeContext);
return (
    <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={ThemeCtx.theme === 'dark'}
      onChange={(e) => {
        ThemeCtx.setTheme(e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light')
      }}
    />
    Use dark mode
  </label>
);
}
```

This is where it gets interesting, to actually update the value of `theme` which is defined in one of the top level components, in this case `App.js` you need to:

1. import `useContext` from 'React'
   `import { useContext } from 'React'`;
2. import ThemeContext from the file you created in step 1.
   `import ThemeContext from '..path/to/file';`
3. create a variable in this component to read from the provider
   `const ThemeCtx = useContext(ThemeContext);`
4. to access the getter (theme) use `ThemeCtx.theme`
5. to update theme via the setter use  `ThemeCtx.setTheme()`

For further reading here is the react documentation for [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) and [createContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext#i-cant-find-a-way-to-change-the-context-value)

Comment: okay bro I'll check

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DevSoni - If you can add some code example demonstrating the issue you’re facing - it would be easier to help

Comment: @nageennayak Updated the answer with more information.

Comment: @DevSoni Hope this update helps, let me know if you need a working example

Comment: @MohammedMuzammil Thank tou so much bro.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a State Management library, like Redux Toolkit. It is easy to understand and also will help you store and update the state of the application.

I didn't use useContext much but maybe you need to check if this is happening only in one use-case - the one you described - or there is a general problem inside the app

Comment: Okay bro I'll check the alternatives of this. like redux

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this can happen, here are a few things to consider when debugging the issue.

1. Are all the components wrapped with your context provider?

   All components must have your custom context provider as a parent wrapper to share its state.
2. The changes being reflected in your current screen, are they being pulled from the context state or a local state?

   If you are getting the data from the context state it means you are on the right track and the issue is in the other components.

   If you are getting it from a local state, it is possible you are not even updating the context properly.